# Finding action-angle variable of given system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

> I need to find the action variable of a particle of mass $m$ moves in a one-dimensional potential $V = V_o \tan^2{\frac{πq}{2a}}$, where $V_o$ and a are potential parameters, and $q$ is the particle co_ordinate. Also what will be the period of motion when $E>>V_o$ & $E<< Vo$.

I have started as below,
\begin{align}
E&=\frac{p^2}{2m}+V_o\tan^2\frac{q\pi}{2a}\, ,\\
p^2 &=2mE-2mV_o\tan^2\frac{q\pi}{2a}\qquad\Rightarrow \qquad p=\sqrt{2mE}\sqrt{1-\frac{V_o\sin^2\frac{q\pi}{2a}}{E \cos^2\frac{q\pi}{2a}}}
\end{align}
Now, 
$$
I= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int{\sqrt{2mE}\sqrt{1-\frac{V_o\sin^2\frac{q\pi}{2a}}{E \cos^2\frac{q\pi}{2a}}}dq}
$$ 
I am stuck with this. How to choose limits? Can we write, 
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{2\pi}\int{\sqrt{2mE}\sqrt{1-\frac{V_o\sin^2\frac{q\pi}{2a}}{E \cos^2\frac{q\pi}{2a}}}dq}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{2\pi}\int
{\frac{1+\frac{V_o^2}{E^2}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{V_o\sin^2\frac{q\pi}{2a}}{E \cos^2\frac{q\pi}{2a}}}}dq}-\frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{2\pi}\int{\frac{\frac{V_o^2}{E^2\cos^2\frac{q\pi}{2a}}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{V_o\sin^2\frac{q\pi}{2a}}{E \cos^2\frac{q\pi}{2a}}}}dq}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limits of integration are the turning points of the motion, i.e.
you need to integrate between $q_1$ and $q_2$ such that
$$
V_0\tan^2\frac{\pi q_1}{2a}=V_0\tan^2\frac{\pi q_2}{2a}=E\, .
$$
The [substitution needed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131086/help-with-a-definite-integral-of-the-type-sqrt1-a-tan2-x) to complete the integral is of the type
$$
q=\arctan\left(\frac{\nu}{\sqrt{A(1+\nu^2)}}\right)\, .
$$

Comment: :Could you explain a bit how to get the limits in this integral

Comment: @Icchyamoy I'm sorry but I'm not sure I understand your question.  The action integral is $\int pdq$ so you need to find the range of $q$ for the motion, and the motion is bounded by the turning points.  To find the turning points set $p=0$ in the expression of the energy (since there is no kinetic energy at the turning points).   For given $E$ the turning points $\{q_1,q_2\}$ are solutions to $V_0\tan^2\frac{\pi q}{2a}=E$.  The integral then goes $\int_{q_1}^{q_2}$.

Comment: For this case, we will have q1 not necessarily equal to q2 but what if the potential function was different?

Comment: @HeroTheZero : Actually, I would appreciate very much if you could answer this:https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/364712/evaluating-limits-of-action-angle-problems?noredirect=1#comment816666_364712

Comment: @Icchyamoy I'll have a look but it's very busy now so it may take a while.