# Evaluating limits of action angle problems

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I am really troubled with finding the limits in "action-angle integral" problems. It is said that the limit is taken over generalised coordinate $q$ such that we have a complete liberation or rotation in the $p$ vs $q$ space. But how can we get this limit?

considering a particular problem, let's say $V(x)=F|x|$ is given.
Then the variable $J$ the is defined as $J= \int_a^bdx({2mE-2mF|x|})^{1/2} $ where E is a constant.

How do I evaluate $a$ and $b$ now? Is there a general scheme that we can use for such problems?

Comment: They are evaluated as classical turning points of the trajectory of a system with energy $E$.

Comment: @confused : Could you please explain a bit more. How is the turning points evaluated and why it had to be the turning points

Comment: You can look into Goldstein's classical mechanics for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general start with 
$$
E=\frac{p^2}{2m}+V(x)\, .  \tag{1}
$$
For a given $E$ the turning points of the motion $x_\pm$ are at found when $V(x_\pm)=E$  since, at the turning points, there is no kinetic energy (the momentum $p=0$).  The turning points define the boundaries of your motion and thus your integration limits.

Reorganize (1) into
$$
p=\pm\sqrt{2m(E-V(x))}\, 
$$
and integrate.  Because of the sign change in $p$ the integration over a full cycle ought to be broken into a part where $p>0$ and a part where $p<0$.  It shouldn’t be too hard to justify that
$$
J=2\int_{x_-}^{x_+} \sqrt{2m(E-V(x))}dx\, , 
$$
so it’ s just a job of finding $x_\pm$ for your specific potential.

[Nota: your potential is $k\vert x\vert$ but your integral has instead $F\vert x\vert$.  I presume there’s a typo somewhere]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I get it now. Basically, you need to find the "area within the curve" if it is closed use symmetry (if any) and get the value. And about the typo. I have fixed it.